# What's the difference between binary and executable files mentioned in ndisasm's manual?

Tags: c, clang, disassembly

I want to compile my C file with `clang` and then decompile it with with `ndisasm` (for educational purposes). However, `ndisasm` says in it's manual that it only works with *binary* and not *executable* files:

```
   ndisasm only disassembles binary files: it  has
   no  understanding  of  the  header  information
   present in object or executable files.  If  you
   want  to disassemble an object file, you should
   probably be using objdump(1).
```

What's the difference, exactly? And what does `clang` output when I run it with a simple C file, an executable or a binary?

Comment: You don't need to disassemble, use the `-s` swtich and that should generate assembly.

Comment: I don't need to do anything, I'm doing it out of curiosity. And I'm curious about how people disassemble binaries, so I learn with my own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object file contains machine language code, *and* all sorts of other information.  It sounds like `ndisasm` wants just the machine code, not the other stuff.  So the message is telling you to use the `objdump` utility to extract just the machine code segment(s) from the object file.  Then you can presumably run `ndisasm` on that.

Comment: In particular, executable files start with a header telling the OS what to load, where to relocate, what portions of the entire file *are* executable and so on. `ndisasm` will gleefully "disassemble" that meta-information when asked, but there is no point in doing so. That's what the quote states.

Comment: Your next question is likely to be "Okay, what's the right `objdump` option to extract just the code segment, in binary?", and I just skimmed the `objdump` man page myself, and I can't see it, either.  Hopefully someone else will be able to help with that part.

Comment: It seems `objdump` comes with its own disassembler. Isn't there a tool to extract code out of an object file?  `ndisasm`  is deliberately kept simple - if you want it to skip a header, you need to find out its size with other means, and then feed that number into it.

Answer (score 1):

> And what does clang output when I run it with a simple C file, an executable or a binary?

A C compiler is usually able to create a 'raw' binary, which is Just The Code, hold the tomato, because for some (rare!) purposes that can be useful. Think, for instance, of boot sectors (which cannot 'load' an executable the regular way because the OS to load them is not yet started) and of programmable RAM chips. An Operating system in itself usually does not like to execute 'raw binary code' - pretty much for the same reasons. An exception is MS Windows, which still can run old format `.com` binaries.

By default, clang will create an *executable*. The intermediate files, called *object files*, are usually deleted after the executable is *linked* (glued together with library functions and an appropriate executable header). To get just a `.o` object file, use the `-c` switch.

Note that Object files also contain a header. After all, the linker needs to know what the file contains before it can link it to other parts.

For educational purposes, you may want to examine the object file format. Armed with that knowledge it should be possible to write a program that can *tell* you at what offset in the file the actual code starts. Then you can feed that information into `ndisasm`.

In addition to the header, files may contain even more data after the instructions. Again, `ndisasm` does not know and nor does it care. If your test program contains a string `Hello world!` somewhere at the end, it will happily try to disassemble that as well. It's up to you to recognize this garbage as such, and ignore what `ndisasm` does to it.